# Show that the interior radius of a compact set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

The problem: *Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Define the interior radius of $A$ by $r(A) = \sup\{r > 0\mid \exists a \in A: B_d(a, r) \subset A\}$. Suppose that $A$ is a compact subset that has interior points. Show that 1.) $r(A)$ is finite 2.) there exists $c \in A$ for which $B_d(c, r(A)) \subset A$.*

My thoughts on the first one: I have a feeling that the way to show that the interior radius of $A$ is finite is to use the sequential compactness of $A$. I do not think that the covering compactness is of any use here. However I could be wrong.

Currently the following is my best shot at the problem: If it were possible to construct a sequence in $A$ such that the members of the sequence have a connection to the distance from an arbitrary interior point of $A$, it could be possible to argue that since $A$ is sequentially compact set, and as the aforementioned sequence is in $A$, the sequence must have a converging subsequence in $A$. And then by ??? the converging subsequence shows that the interior radius is finite.

Comment: Assume $A\subseteq B_R(x_0)$ for some $R>0$ and $x_0\in X$. Then we can show that $r(A)<R$. So to bound $r(A)$ from above it is enoug to show that compact sets are bounded. For the lower bound, all we need to show that there exists some $a\in A$ and some $r>0$ such that $B_r(a)\subseteq A$ (which follows from the assumption that $A$ has nonempty interior).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Why is it necessary to bound $r(A)$ from below?

Comment: Because bounded is the same as being bounded above and bounded below :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ah, true! On the other hand, isn't the $r(A)$ already bounded by zero from below?

Comment: Only if you have an interior point. For example $r(\emptyset)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I begin by commenting something that really got me confused at first. In the statements, you really need $\subset$ without equality being allowed, otherwise the statement as you put it is not true: take $X = A= [0, 1]$ with $d$ the regular metric. This $X$ has certainly interior points, but the distance between any two points is bounded by $1$, which means that after you start considering balls of radius bigger than 1, you already have the whole space $X$ which of course is inside *or equal to* $X = A$ and so the radius would simply blow up, and not being finite.

So, with this in mind, what $r(A)$ has to mean is
$$
r(A) = \sup\{r > 0 \mid \exists\; a\in A \; s.t. B_d(a, r)\subsetneq A\}.
$$

Even more, we can consider the trivial metric on any set $X$ and consider $A = \{a\}$. Then $a$ would be an interior point since $A = B(1, a)$, so $A$ would be a compact set with interior point not satisfying the conclusions since every ball with center in the point of $A$ would contain $A$, and so we would have and $r(A) = r(\emptyset) = -\infty$, which is not finite, so again the statement would be false.

So, we will asume: $A$ is not a single point and that $r(A)$ means what is stated above.

We will sometimes abuse notation and refer to $r(A)$ also as the subset over which the supremum is being taken here.

Now we are ready to prove the statement:

We prove $r(A)$ is nonempty first. We need to prove this since the definition of interior point allows for the inclusion to be not strict, so that the interior point is not autmatically what we want since it might be the case that $A$ is the whole open ball of the interior point.

Suppose $i$ is an interior point and $r>0$ such that $B_d(i, r)\subseteq A$. If inclusion is strict then we are done as then $r\in R(A)$. Otherwise $B_d(i, r) = A$. If $r' < r$ then $B_d(i, r')\subseteq B_d(i, r) = A$. If at some point, $0 < r' < r$ the inclusion becomes strict then we are done again as $r'\in r(A)$. Suppose then this is not the case, and that $A = B_d(i, r')$ for all $r'\le r$. Then, of course, for any $a\in A$ we have that $d(a, i)\le r'\rightarrow 0$ and so $a = i$. That is $A = \{i\}$, which means $A$ is a single point, which contradicts our assumptions. So, at some point the inclusion becomes strict, and so, $r(A)$ is nonempty.

Notice that because $A$ is compact then $A\times A\subset X\times X$ is also compact. The distance function $d:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous in the product topology, and as such $d(A\times A)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, that is, closed and bounded. In particular, there exists a positive $M$ such that $d(x, y)\le M$ as long as $x, y\in A$.

We now prove $r(A)$ is finite. We already proved the set is nonempty, so in order to prove it has a supremum we must prove it is boundad above (Also notice, below its bounded by $0$ since we are considering radius). Pick $r\in r(A)$ and $a\in A$ such that the definition of the set holds for this $r$. There exists a $c\in A - B_d(a, r)$, by our assumption on the definition of $r(A)$. Then of course we have $d(c, a)\ge r$, since it not in the ball, but also $d(c, a)\le M$ since both $c$ and $a$ are in $A$. We conclude
$$
r\le M.
$$
Since $M$ was found depending only on $A$ but not in its particular elements, we have that $M$ is an upper bound for the non empty set and so the supremum $r(A)$ exists and is finite.

Now we prove part (ii):

Since $A$ is compact and $r(A)$ is the supremum we can suppose that there exists a  sequence $r_1, r_2,...$ converging to $r(A) =: r$ and a convergent sequence $a_1, a_2,...$ to a point $a\in A$ such that $B_d(a_n, r_n)\subset A$. We used the compactness of $A$ to find this convergent sequence to a point $a \in A$.

Pick $x\in B_d(a, r(A))$, which makes sense since $r(A)$ is a positive number. Now we claim there is an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x, a_m) < r_m$. Suppose on the contrary. We would have, for all positive integers $n$,
$$
r_n \le d(x, a_n) 
$$
Taking the limit, as $n\mapsto\infty$, and using that the distance function is continuous with respect to a topology it creates, we have
$$
r(A) \le d(x, a) < r(A).
$$
This cannot happen, so such $m$ must exist with $d(x, a_m) < r_m$. By definition we then conclude $x\in B_d(a_m, r_m)\subset A$. Varying $x\in B_d(a, r(A))$ we have $B_d(a, r(A))\subseteq A$, as desired.

In order to finish, we need to prove the inclusion is strict. For each $n$ we can find also, by definition of $r(A)$, a point $c_n\in A$, such that $d(c_n, a_n) \ge r_n$. Furhtermore, by compactness we can assume, maybe after going to a subsequece and relabeling the indices, that $c_n\rightarrow c\in A$. If we take limit in $d(c_n, a_n)\ge r_n$, we deduce, $d(c, a)\ge r(A)$ so that $c\notin B_d(a, r(A))$. Hence,
$$
B_d(a, r(A))\subsetneq A
$$
and so $a$ is the point we were looking for in $(ii)$.
This concludes the proof.

Comment: This is one of the most comprehensive answers I have received in this site so far! I am following everything else except the issue which arises if we would allow the inclusion of the ball around the interior point be non-strict. Specifically, is the issue that since no properties of the metric were specified in the problem statement, we could choose the 0/1 metric (or something else?), so that if $ \#A = 1$, then the radius could be arbitrarily large?

Comment: Yes, if we allow for nonstrict, we can pick particular metric spaces such that the radius can be arbitrarily large, and if we let $A$ be a single point we can have $r(A)$ is a supremum of an empty set, which again causes trouble.

Comment: @MEEL Nice answer (+1). Though I would consider it more natural to assume that $X$ is unbounded (then we can keep the original definition) as I like to keep the point :) anyways that is just a matter of taste.